# migration error in cassandra

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cassandra

i am using cassandra in my rails project, I am new to this cassandra and i am trying to use Bigrecord api to connect with cassandra and i reffered below link

http://openplaces.github.com/bigrecord/file.getting_started.html

while migrating the bigrecord i am using this command  **rake bigrecord:migrate** but it is showing some error like this

**rake aborted!**
**This database does not yet support migrations**

can any one help me to solve this problem

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Bigrecord currently only supports HBase. Cassandra is not yet supported.